# How to use typing overrides for pandas, torch, and numpy inputs

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, mypy, python-typing

I'm currently trying setup overloaded type definitions for my module to show that passing a data type will return the same type. My current module looks like:

```
class MyModule:

    @overload
    def __call__(self, inputs: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        ...

    @overload
    def __call__(self, inputs: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        ...

    @overload
    def __call__(self, inputs: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        ...

    def __call__(self, inputs: np.ndarray | torch.Tensor | pd.DataFrame):
        pass
```

However, mypy is raising errors about this:

```
utils.py:71: error: Overloaded function signature 2 will never be matched: signature 1's parameter type(s) are the same or broader  [misc]
utils.py:71: error: Overloaded function signature 3 will never be matched: signature 1's parameter type(s) are the same or broader  [misc]
utils.py:71: error: Overloaded function signature 3 will never be matched: signature 2's parameter type(s) are the same or broader  [misc]
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 21 source files)
```

Instances of the three types do not return `True` for `isinstance` tests, so I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting these errors.

Edit:
Package versions: `mypy==1.2.0`, `torch==2.0.0`, `numpy==1.24.3`, `pandas==2.0.1`, and `pandas-stubs==2.0.1.230501`.

Added `reveal_type(pandas.DataFrame)`, `reveal_type(np.ndarray)`, and `reveal_type(torch.Tensor)` to the file and ran mypy on it. Got this as part of the output, but got the same errors as above as well:

```
utils.py:13: note: Revealed type is "Overload(def (data: Union[Union[typing.Sequence[Any], numpy.ndarray[Any, Any], pandas.core.series.Series[Any], pandas.core.indexes.base.Index], pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, builtins.dict[Any, Any], typing.Iterable[Union[Union[typing.Sequence[Any], numpy.ndarray[Any, Any], pandas.core.series.Series[Any], pandas.core.indexes.base.Index], Tuple[typing.Hashable, Union[typing.Sequence[Any], numpy.ndarray[Any, Any], pandas.core.series.Series[Any], pandas.core.indexes.base.Index]], builtins.dict[Any, Any]]], None] =, index: Union[Union[pandas.core.indexes.base.Index, pandas.core.series.Series[Any], numpy.ndarray[Any, Any], builtins.list[Any], builtins.dict[Any, Any], builtins.range, builtins.tuple[Any, ...]], None] =, columns: Union[Union[pandas.core.indexes.base.Index, pandas.core.series.Series[Any], numpy.ndarray[Any, Any], builtins.list[Any], builtins.dict[Any, Any], builtins.range, builtins.tuple[Any, ...]], None] =, dtype: Any =, copy: builtins.bool =) -> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, def (data: Union[builtins.str, builtins.bytes, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, datetime.timedelta, numpy.datetime64, numpy.timedelta64, builtins.bool, builtins.int, builtins.float, pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp, pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta, builtins.complex], index: Union[pandas.core.indexes.base.Index, pandas.core.series.Series[Any], numpy.ndarray[Any, Any], builtins.list[Any], builtins.dict[Any, Any], builtins.range, builtins.tuple[Any, ...]], columns: Union[pandas.core.indexes.base.Index, pandas.core.series.Series[Any], numpy.ndarray[Any, Any], builtins.list[Any], builtins.dict[Any, Any], builtins.range, builtins.tuple[Any, ...]], dtype: Any =, copy: builtins.bool =) -> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame)"
utils.py:14: note: Revealed type is "def [_ShapeType <: Any, _DType_co <: numpy.dtype[Any]] (shape: Union[typing.SupportsIndex, typing.Sequence[typing.SupportsIndex]], dtype: Union[numpy.dtype[Any], None, Type[Any], numpy._typing._dtype_like._SupportsDType[numpy.dtype[Any]], builtins.str, Tuple[Any, builtins.int], Tuple[Any, Union[typing.SupportsIndex, typing.Sequence[typing.SupportsIndex]]], builtins.list[Any], TypedDict('numpy._typing._dtype_like._DTypeDict', {'names': typing.Sequence[builtins.str], 'formats': typing.Sequence[Any], 'offsets'?: typing.Sequence[builtins.int], 'titles'?: typing.Sequence[Any], 'itemsize'?: builtins.int, 'aligned'?: builtins.bool}), Tuple[Any, Any]] =, buffer: Union[builtins.bytes, builtins.bytearray, builtins.memoryview, array.array[Any], mmap.mmap, numpy.ndarray[Any, numpy.dtype[Any]], numpy.generic] =, offset: typing.SupportsIndex =, strides: Union[typing.SupportsIndex, typing.Sequence[typing.SupportsIndex]] =, order: Union[None, Literal['K'], Literal['A'], Literal['C'], Literal['F']] =) -> numpy.ndarray[_ShapeType`1, _DType_co`2]"
utils.py:15: note: Revealed type is "Overload(def (*args: Any, *, device: Union[torch._C.device, builtins.str, builtins.int, None] =) -> torch._tensor.Tensor, def (storage: torch.types.Storage) -> torch._tensor.Tensor, def (other: torch._tensor.Tensor) -> torch._tensor.Tensor, def (size: Union[torch._C.Size, builtins.list[builtins.int], builtins.tuple[builtins.int, ...]], *, device: Union[torch._C.device, builtins.str, builtins.int, None] =) -> torch._tensor.Tensor)"
```

Comment: `numpy` has a `typing` module.  Does pandas or pytorch have anything like that?   A dataframe has attributes which are arrays, but it does not subclass `ndarray`.  Same for tensor.

Comment: (Blind guess) You're getting this error, because `pandas` is untyped, and you probably have no stubs installed. If you have not very modern torch, it's untyped as well. So at least two first signatures render as `def __call__(self, inputs: Any) -> Any`, and this covers everything. To verify, please do `reveal_type(pd.DataFrame)` and `reveal_type(torch.Tensor)` and add `mypy` output to your question.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Installed `pandas-stubs` and included the `reveal_type`s above. Problem persists.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `overload` for this; just make `__call__` generic.

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', pd.DataFrame, torch.Tensor, np.ndarray)


class MyModule:

    def __call__(self, inputs: T) -> T:
        ...


m = MyModule()

df1 = pd.Dataframe()
t1: torch.Tensor = ...

df2: pd.DataFrame = m(df1)  # OK
# t2: torch.Tensor = m(df1)  # ERROR: got pd.Dataframe, expected torch.Tensor

t3: torch.Tensor = m(t1)  # OK
```

`MyModule.__call__` will only accept an instance of one of the three types listed in the definition of `T`, and the return type of any individual call will match the type of the argument.

Comment: While this does solve the problem, it doesn't answer how to use overload in this spot. Is this an issue with Mypy not working or something else failing?